# Boost compilation with different compiler than used for other sources

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

Should there be a problem to compile static boost libraries (thread, filesystem, etc.) with one gcc version (4.6) and the rest of the code (uses boost headers) with another (4.7)?

I had a compilation error which was solved once everything was compiled with gcc4.7.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it shouldn't be a problem, because the GCC maintains a stable C++ ABI across compiler versions.
In practice, sometimes there are ABI compliance bugs, which may get fixed (or introduced), but my experience is that this issue is a very low risk.